# Lyapunov Theorem - Linear System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In some literatur is written (e.g. lin. discrete systems):

For all $Q > 0$ there is a unique solution $P > 0$ to the equation $A^T P A - P = -Q$  <=> $A$ is asymptotically stable

From this, can i conlcude the following?:

- If i can find a $P>0$ satisfying the above equation with $Q>0$, is
  the system asymptotically stable?
- If i can find a $Q>0$ and a solution $P>0$ to the above equation, is
  the system asymptotically stable?

The question in another way is: if the equation has a unique solution $P<0$ for one 
specific $Q>0$ can i conclude the equation has a unique solution for all $Q>0$?

i am a little bit confused here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement means that if you can find a $P>0$ for *some* $Q>0$, then you can find a $P>0$ for *all* $Q>0$ and the system is asymptotically stable (and vice versa). Also $P$ is unique for each $Q$.

Also, if a $P>0$ does not exist for *some* $Q>0$, then it does not exist for *all* $Q>0$ and the system is not asymptotically stable (and vice versa).